# multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback, TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'Feature2D' or its derivative)

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing

I want to calculate keypoints and descriptors with openCV brisk using python multiprocessing. When I run the following codes, some errors happened.But when I run the codes with python threading, it will be OK.

```
import cv2
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.brisk = cv2.BRISK_create(thresh=70, octaves=4)

    def apply_brisk(self, test_img_path):
        # brisk = cv2.BRISK_create(thresh=70, octaves=4)

        frame = cv2.imread(test_img_path)
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img_kp = self.brisk.detect(img_gray, None)
        img_kp, img_des = self.brisk.compute(img_gray, img_kp)
        print(img_kp)
        print(img_des)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test images directory
    test_images_dir = '/home/limin/pcb/images'
    test_images_name = [f for f in os.listdir(test_images_dir)]

    p = Pool(4)
    for test in test_images_name:
        # test image path
        test_image_path = test_images_dir + '/' + test

        t = Test()
        p.apply(t.apply_brisk, (test_image_path,))
        # p.apply_async(t.apply_brisk, (test_image_path,))

    p.close()
    p.join()
```

**Errors:**

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/limin/Desktop/classifier_cv_tf/test.py", line 15, in apply_brisk
    img_kp = self.brisk.detect(img_gray, None)
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'Feature2D' or its derivative)
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/limin/Desktop/classifier_cv_tf/test.py", line 32, in <module>
    p.apply(t.apply_brisk, (test_image_path,))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 253, in apply
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'Feature2D' or its derivative)
```

When I change the position of 'BRISK' object, errors will missing:

```
import cv2
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        # self.brisk = cv2.BRISK_create(thresh=70, octaves=4)
        pass

    def apply_brisk(self, test_img_path):
        brisk = cv2.BRISK_create(thresh=70, octaves=4)

        frame = cv2.imread(test_img_path)
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img_kp = brisk.detect(img_gray, None)
        img_kp, img_des = brisk.compute(img_gray, img_kp)
        print(img_kp)
        print(img_des)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test images directory
    test_images_dir = '/home/limin/pcb/images'
    test_images_name = [f for f in os.listdir(test_images_dir)]

    p = Pool(4)
    for test in test_images_name:
        # test image path
        test_image_path = test_images_dir + '/' + test

        t = Test()
        p.apply(t.apply_brisk, (test_image_path,))
        # p.apply_async(t.apply_brisk, (test_image_path,))

    p.close()
    p.join()
```

**Environments:**

- Ubuntu16.04
- python3.5
- opencv3.4.8

I am wondering about this, who can help me if I want to use python multiprocessing in the codes. Thank you!

Comment: You run this remote? How exactly? I'm wondering why you don't already get `TypeError: can't pickle cv2.BRISK objects` in the parent since BRISK objects
are not pickleable. Check this with `pickle.dumps(Test())`.

Comment: Temporarily run in local machine.  Test() can pickle dumps. I use Process instead of Pool, and it works.

Comment: It works with `Process` instead of `Pool` because there is no pickling involved since your OS uses fork to start new processes.
When you use `Pool` however, pickling will always happen because the arguments willl be send over a queue. The strange thing is, that pickling silently creates a shallow copy in your case , one which doesn't include the brisk instance. Which IDE do you use for running this?

Comment: @7wdeepin I am getting the same error in a Flask app - did you get to the bottom of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import os
from multiprocessing import Process


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.brisk = cv2.BRISK_create(thresh=70, octaves=4)

    def apply_brisk(self, test_img_path):
        frame = cv2.imread(test_img_path)
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img_kp = self.brisk.detect(img_gray, None)
        img_kp, img_des = self.brisk.compute(img_gray, img_kp)
        print(img_kp)
        print(img_des)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test images directory
    test_images_dir = '/home/limin/pcb/images'
    test_images_name = [f for f in os.listdir(test_images_dir)]

    # subprocess
    ps = []
    t = Test()

    for test in test_images_name:
        # test image path
        test_image_path = test_images_dir + '/' + test

        p = Process(target=t.apply_brisk, args=(test_image_path,))
        ps.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in ps:
        p.join()
```